# Ubuntu clean install - no OS detected

Tags: 16.04, boot

I have recently taken to installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 on my Lenovo M92 Tiny which previously had Windows on it. I don't want to run Windows any more so don't care about multi-boot.

I have installed Ubuntu from a USB stick using the `erase-disk` option. The install runs fine and then asks to reboot at which point I just keep getting the error message from the BIOS

> No OS Found - press any key to repeat boot sequence.

I have run `boot-repair` a couple of times, but it does not seem to make any difference. Below is the paste of the boot-repair output.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6hGPZWMwWT/

Any pointers/advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: maybe this can help:


https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175250

Comment: Thansk for the pointer Sadegh. Based on the article I am going to reset my BIOS settings and try to re-install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

So, thank you to the pointer from Sadegh I set my BIOS to BIOS boot mode and re-installed Ubuntu using the installed off a USB stick. All seems to be working now.

Thanks again.